# No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, spring-3

I'm getting following exception after migrating to Spring Framework 3.1.0 RC1 with Hibernate 4.0.0 CR7

> 2011-12-08/11:48:38.425/EST [Thread-17] ERROR Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:530)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:459)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
>       at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
>       ... 18 more

Comment: Does PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor require any other beans to be defined.  I have never used it before, but I'm guessing that's what is causing your error.

Comment: Looks like, you need to define one of the derivatives of [PersistenceExceptionTranslator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslator.html) in bean configuration.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

And with the new spring java configuration :

```
    @Bean 
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){ 
      return new HibernateExceptionTranslator(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 23):

As mentioned by skravin, you must configure a [`HibernateExceptionTranslator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateExceptionTranslator.html). The `LocalSessionFactoryBean` for Hibernate 3 implements `PersistenceExceptionTranslator`, but the one for Hibernate 4 does not.

Comment: What it means "to configure HibernateExceptionTranslator"? I follow this doc http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ and it does not mention it? Thanks.

Comment: Just declare a bean of this type in your spring context XML file.

Comment: But how exactly? <bean id="HibernateExceptionTranslator"></bean> Does not work obviously. I wonder why it is not documented in the official tutorial. Thanks

Comment: <bean id="someId" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

Comment: Brilliant, the id="someId" is obviously not even necessary. Thanks!